# Meteor-react-autoform not showing anything

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-react

I have been struggling with this a couple of weeks.
I want to use [meteor-react-autoform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/meteor-react-autoform) in my web page.
I'm using [Base](https://themeteorchef.com/base/) from The Meteor Chef.
Any help is really appreciated

Sorry for the bad english, here are the files.

This is the file where I define my Schema and Collection:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { SimpleSchema } from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';
import { Factory } from 'meteor/dburles:factory';

export const Documents = new Mongo.Collection('Documents');

// Documentation -> https://github.com/MechJosh0/meteor-react-autoform
// Extend the schema to allow our materialForm object
SimpleSchema.extendOptions({
    materialForm: Match.Optional(Object)
});


Documents.allow({
  insert: () => false,
  update: () => false,
  remove: () => false
});

Documents.deny({
  insert: () => true,
  update: () => true,
  remove: () => true
});

Documents.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
      materialForm: {
          floatingLabelText: 'Your name',
          hintText: 'Sarah Smith...'
    }
  }
});

Documents.attachSchema(Documents.schema);
```

Here is the Form and the Insert Handler

```
import React from 'react';
import { Bert } from 'meteor/themeteorchef:bert';
import { insertDocument } from '../../api/documents/methods.js';
import ReactAutoForm from 'meteor-react-autoform';
import { Documents } from '../../api/documents/documents';


const handleInsertDocument = (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  const title = target.value.trim();

  if (title !== '' && event.keyCode === 13) {
    insertDocument.call({
      title
    }, (error) => {
      if (error) {
        Bert.alert(error.reason, 'danger');
      } else {
        target.value = '';
        Bert.alert('Document added!', 'success');
      }
    });
  }
};


export const AddDocument = () => (
    <ReactAutoForm
        muiTheme={true}
        onSubmit={handleInsertDocument}
        schema={Documents.schema}
        type="insert"
    />
);
```

This is the file with the method defined:

```
import { Documents } from './documents';
import { SimpleSchema } from 'meteor/aldeed:simple-schema';
import { ValidatedMethod } from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method';

export const insertDocument = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'documents.insert',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    title: { type: String }
  }).validator(),
  run(document) {
    Documents.insert(document);
  }
});

export const updateDocument = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'documents.update',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    _id: { type: String },
    'update.title': { type: String, optional: true }
  }).validator(),
  run({ _id, update }) {
    Documents.update(_id, { $set: update });
  }
});

export const removeDocument = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'documents.remove',
  validate: new SimpleSchema({
    _id: { type: String }
  }).validator(),
  run({ _id }) {
    Documents.remove(_id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your collection and schema need to be defined separately in different files. Move your schema into a new file, import the schema into your collection file and transfer it through SimeplSchema and store as the collection. Then in the react file you import the schema file, not the collection file.

Example can be found on [the readme file](https://github.com/Aluminati/meteor-react-autoform#simpleschema-object).

If you're still having problems I suggest creating a project on Github that you can share where you're reproducing the problem, submit an issue on meteor-react-autoform project I'll submit a pull request with the changes to get your project working.